# How to select a handshake and code examples in verilog

Tags: verilog

I'm new to Verilog, and I was taking a look into the ready-valid handshake. I saw that this is the most used handshake, as it is simple to understand. However, I couldn't find the disadvantages of this handshake. So my first question is:

- Are there any cases when the ready-valid is not well-suited for specific scenarios?
- Do any specific rules exist to keep in mind when implementing handshakes?
- Are there any repository where I can find a simple implementation of a ready-valid example in Verilog?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You might find this helpful: Rules for Ready/Valid Handshakes http://fpgacpu.ca/fpga/handshake.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ready-valid is very good in a synchronous design, because it allows high bandwidth (transfer on every clock cycle) and precise flow control. That's why it's used in the [AXI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_eXtensible_Interface) interface, which is the basis for much vendor IP -- and also my own IP.

For example, here's a module from my own library. The "v" on the input and output ports comes from the fact that much of my work is with video transferred on AXI streams.

```vhdl
/* axi_one_stage_fifo.v */

/* This module is the simplest possible AXI FIFO. It demonstrates the basics of
 * the AXI handshake, and can also be used as the output stage of more complex
 * processing modules.
 *
 * This is a fall-though FIFO -- the data appears on the output pins regardless
 * of the state of vout_tready.
 *
 * The disadvantage compared to the two-stage FIFO is that the flow control path
 * (TREADY) is combinatorial, which can create long timing paths.
 */

module axi_one_stage_fifo #(
  parameter TDATA_WIDTH = 1,
  parameter TUSER_WIDTH = 1
) (
  /* AXI in */
  output                vin_tready,
  input                 vin_tvalid,
  input [TDATA_WIDTH-1:0] vin_tdata,
  input [TUSER_WIDTH-1:0] vin_tuser,
  input                 vin_tlast,
  /* AXI out */
  input                 vout_tready,
  output reg            vout_tvalid,
  output reg [TDATA_WIDTH-1:0] vout_tdata,
  output reg [TUSER_WIDTH-1:0] vout_tuser,
  output reg            vout_tlast,
  /* clock, reset */
  input                 clock,
  input                 reset
);

  wire          xfer_in = vin_tready & vin_tvalid;
  wire          xfer_out = vout_tready & vout_tvalid;

  assign vin_tready = vout_tready | !vout_tvalid;

  always @(posedge clock) begin
    if (reset) begin
      vout_tvalid <= 0;
    end else begin
      if (xfer_in) begin
        vout_tvalid <= 1;
        vout_tdata <= vin_tdata;
        vout_tuser <= vin_tuser;
        vout_tlast <= vin_tlast;
      end else if (xfer_out) begin
        vout_tvalid <= 0;
      end
    end
  end
   
endmodule
```